# Swiftmailer cannot connect to mail server

Tags: php, laravel-5.1, swiftmailer

I use swiftmailer in Laravel 5.1 to send email. The swiftmailer works fine at my local machine but at production server, it sometimes cannot connect to email server (connection time out #110).

My firewall allowed all from host to mail server.

How can I fixed?

Comment: Are you using Gmail SMTP?

Comment: @Nikhil My company is use Microsoft Exchange 2010 to Email server.

Comment: Possible dup: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25517281/swiftmailer-connection-could-not-be-established-with-host-smtp-gmail-com-conne