# swift mail not working in the live but working in local why?

Tags: php, codeigniter, swiftmailer

```
// Create the mail transport configuration
$transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('smtp.gmail.com', 465, 'ssl')
    ->setUsername(PASUPUKUMKUMA_EMAIL)
    ->setPassword(PASUPUKUMKUMA_PASS);


// Create the message
$message = Swift_Message::newInstance()
    ->setTo(array($email => $name))
    ->setSubject("Registration Success !")
    ->setBody('You have Registered Successfully ! Thank You For Registering With Us.Click the link to confirm your account <a href='.site_url().'/main/confirm/'.$name.'/'.$ran.'>confirm here</a>', 'text/html')
    ->setFrom(PASUPUKUMKUMA_EMAIL,EMAIL_FROM_NAME);

// Send the email
$mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);
$mailer->send($message);
```

This is my code for sending email through swift mailer everything was perfect when I send the mail in the local I can be able to send the mail successfully.

When comes to live website with the same code not able to send the mail and shows the error:

```
Connection could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com..
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25517281/swiftmailer-connection-could-not-be-established-with-host-smtp-gmail-com-conne   : Try the solution given here.

Comment: already tried,but no use..

Answer (score 0):

https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps

Turn it on for the account that you are using. Hope it will help.