# Swiftmailer: Connection refused #111

Tags: php, email, smtp, gmail, swiftmailer

I am trying to use swiftmailer to send emails from my website however when I run the php script I get the following error:

> Uncaught exception 'Swift_TransportException' with message 'Connection
>   could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com [Connection refused #111]'

and the code I am using looks like this:

```
require_once "vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/swift_required.php";

$transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('smtp.gmail.com', 465, "ssl")

    ->setUsername("EMAIL")

    ->setPassword('PASSWORD');

$mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);

$message = Swift_Message::newInstance('Website Enquiry')

    ->setFrom(array($email))

    ->setTo(array('MY EMAIL'))

    ->setBody($msg);

$result = $mailer->send($message);

echo $result;
return $result;
```

Any help would be much appriciated. Thanks!

(This is not a duplicate of [Swiftmailer: Connection could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com [Connection timed out #110]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25517281/swiftmailer-connection-could-not-be-established-with-host-smtp-gmail-com-conne) because of the different code (#110 vs #111) and because I didn't set up swiftmailer using configuration but instead in my code. I'm not sure if that makes sense, but basically the answers in the other question don't solve my question.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swiftmailer: Connection could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com \[Connection timed out #110\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25517281/swiftmailer-connection-could-not-be-established-with-host-smtp-gmail-com-conne)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, there isn't any solution. It turns out that GoDaddy (my web host) blocks ports 25 and 465 (and another SMTP one that I cant remember). So the only solution is switching hosts.

Answer (score 0):

GoDaddy may block those ports, but you can use sendmail to send the message. See the example below:

```
$transport = new Swift_SendmailTransport('/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs');
```